# In a $\triangle ABC$, prove $(a+b+c)\left(\tan\frac{A}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}\right) = 2 c \cot\frac{C}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

This is a question I was sent by a Pakistani friend, it appeared on his 11th grade examination from last year. He could not solve it, so he decided to skip this one.

> In a triangle $ABC$, prove that
> $$(a+b+c)\left(\tan\frac{A}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}\right) = 2 c \cot\frac{C}{2}$$

I solved this problem in a fairly brute force manner, using a half-angle formula which, according to him, was something that was NOT included in their mathematics syllabus for the year 2021. So I'm posting this here to see if there can be other better approaches for this. As always, I'll also post my own approach down as an answer.

Comment: It looks to me as though this might be intended to go via the angle bisectors meeting at the in-centre and working with the area of the triangle and the in-radius. Which pretty much would do what you have done, but without knowing the formulae [it would in effect be deriving the formulae].

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, given that they weren't taught the formula last year for some reason. I did try the "derive the formula" approach and I essentially got the same thing. If that's what the examiners intended then I'm glad he skipped it and moved onto an easier question as this would have taken up a lot of his time

Comment: In "Geometry Revisited" by H.S.M. Coxeter (P.12-13), the author did not directly attack this problem. But he had provided sufficient information for a simple and elegant proof for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible more or less geometric approach.
Let $a,b,c$ be the lengths of the sides of the given triangle, and let $I$ be its incenter:

[image: incircle of a triangle with tangency points]

Let $s$ be the half-perimeter, $s=\frac 12(a+b+c)$.
Then the three values $x=AE=AF$, $y=BF=BD$, $z=CD=CE$ are the solutions of the system $y+z=a$, $z+x=b$, $x+y=c$, so $x=s-a$, $y=s-b$, $z=s-c$. We can now translate all quantities in the given relation that has to be shown,
marked with $\overset!=$ ,
so we can equivalently rewrite the given (to-be) relation, where for instance the tangent of $A/2$ is $IE/AE=r/(s-a)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
s\left(\tan\frac A2+\tan\frac B2\right) 
&\overset!= 
c \cot\frac C2\ ,
\\
s\left(\frac r{s-a} + \frac r{s-b}\right) 
&\overset!= 
c \frac {s-c}r\ ,
\\
sr\cdot\frac {(s-a)+(s-b)}{(s-a)(s-b)}
&\overset!= 
c \frac {s-c}r\ ,
\\
sr^2\cdot c &\overset!= c\;(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\ ,
\\
s^2r^2 &\overset!= s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\ ,
\\
s^2r^2 &\overset!= S^2\qquad\text{(Heron formula for the area $S$ of $\Delta ABC$)}\ ,
\\
sr &\overset!= S
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And the last relation is true, it expresses the way to compute $S$, the area of $\Delta ABC$,
as the sum of the three areas

- of $\Delta EBC$ which is $ra/2$,
- of $\Delta ECA$  which is $rb/2$, and
- of $\Delta EAB$  which is $rc/2$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I do not own the honour of discovering the following proof myself. Rather what follows comes from the book "Geometry Revisited " by H.S.M. Coxeter.

The figure is a copy of Figure 1.4B of the book.

On P.13 of the book, Coxeter showed that

(a)  $AY_a=BX_b=s$

(b)  $CX_b=s-a$

(c)  $CX_a=s-b$

From these, the question can be answered easily .

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach for the problem. Forgive me for a less than ideal picture quality.

[image]